# jquery mobile 1.1 rc1 - a href in fixed toolbar not working

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

looks like the z-index overlay of ul lists overlaps the fixed headers and footers, so that a long list, if scrolled is not correctly positioning itself under footers and headers, making contained href links impossible to click...

```
       <div data-role="page" id="two" data-fullscreen="true">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>Whats in my juice?</h1>

          </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">   
           <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" id="ingredients" data-split-icon="delete"></ul>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">


<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="clear" data-icon="delete" class="ui-btn-left">Clear</a> </li>
        <li><a><span class="counta">0 Items</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#save" data-icon="arrow-r" class="ui-btn-right" id="build-save">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->

        </div><!-- /footer -->

    </div><!-- /page -->
```

in the above example the ul list items are generated dynamically.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

is included in the header. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial Fix: add

```
.ui-selectmenu { z-index: 1100 !important; }
```

to your style, resolves button overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

A valid version works here: http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/Eam2y/

I don't see any issues with z-index on the `ul` as you mention.  Could it be some bug in the way you are populating the list with `li` items? It may help to post that code, otherwise check it in a debugger and verify:

1. valid HTML is being added to the dynamically generated list items
2. that you are calling refresh on the list: `$('#mylist').listview();`

Documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an android device, this could be a bug in Android, too. I'm having a similar iisue with overlayed elements.

Comment: yes it is an android device..., partially resolved the issue with adding .ui-selectmenu { z-index: 1100 !important; } to styles, which prevents the overlap. the issue only appears when deplyed to a device, not the emulator

Comment: here is the android bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6721 I'm also working around by disabling buttons in the background